# How to launch rest-spring application on tomcat?

Tags: java, spring

I try to create application on spring with rest-controllers.
The project structure is
[image]

applcationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       ">

    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

RestController is

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getTest(){
        int i = 1;
    }
}
```

So, I deploy this application on apache-tomcat-8.5.29, but there is 404 error when try to call rest..

The url I tried is localhost:8080/test and localhost:8080/appName/test

Do you have any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Try hitting http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: Where is tomcat on your machine and how did you ensure that it knows about this webapp?

Comment: Did you check if the server is running in 8080 port? Do you use a context path `<Context path=`? Are you testing it in local or you're using a tunnel to connect like localhost?

Comment: Where is your spring mvc configuration? Have a look here with various examples https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should use springboot which does not require an external application or web server, instead of bare spring application, after successfully running your springboot application, you can search how to convert a springboot application to able to run on tomcat.

here are some links:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/